# NSE error handling: check for `NA` with NSE/tidy eval

Tags: r, metaprogramming, tidyeval

I am writing a function using `tidyeval`, and I ran into a problem while trying to check for `NA`s.

I am writing a function to make plots using `ggplot2` that looks something like:

```
my_func <- function(data, x = NA, y = NA) {
  if(is.na(x) & is.na(y)) {
    stop("`x` and `y` cannot both be NA.")
  }
  if(is.na(y)) {
    data %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = {{ x }})) + 
      ggplot2::geom_bar()
  } else {
    data %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(y = {{ y }})) + 
      ggplot2::geom_bar()
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
data("iris")
my_func(data = iris, x = Species)

#> Error in my_func(data = iris, x = Species) :
#>   object 'Species' not found
```

I've been learning about NSE and metaprogramming from [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html), but I am still relatively new to this topic.

I have tried this general function using `NA`s and `is.na` and `NULL`s and `is.null`. I know that I am missing something with regards to NSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `missing` to create condition

```
my_func <- function(data, x, y) {
  
  if(missing(y)) {
    data %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = {{ x }})) + 
      ggplot2::geom_bar()
  } else {
    data %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(y = {{ y }})) + 
      ggplot2::geom_bar()
  }
}
```

-testing

```
> my_func(iris, x = Sepal.Length)
> my_func(iris, y = Sepal.Width)
```

Comment: Thank you - this is much cleaner than setting everything to `NA` and makes a lot more sense.